# Using Gradient Decent For PCA Optimization

Tags: machine-learning, pca, optimization, gradient-descent

I'm trying to solve the PCA problem:

For $k\in N$ some number and $X\in R(n\times d)$ where I'm trying to find $w\in R(k\times d)$ such that:

$w = argmax( E(WXX^T))$

(I might be wrong with the formulation of the optimization goal. Please correct me).

I want to solve the optimization goal with gradient decent rather than with SVD decomposition as usual (I have my reasons, I just want to keep this post short).

I'm basing my code on this post:
[Reference of pretty much the same question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/427339/how-can-one-implement-pca-using-gradient-descent).

But, my code doesn't seem to find an optimal solution.

```
def get_gd_pca(X, w):
    k = w.shape[-1]
    LEARNING_RATE = 0.1
    EPOCHS = 200
    cov = torch.cov(X)
    lam = torch.rand(1, requires_grad=True)
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD([w, lam], lr=LEARNING_RATE, maximize=True)
    for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        left_side_loss = torch.matmul(w.T, torch.matmul(cov, w))
        right_side_loss = torch.matmul((lam * torch.eye(k)), (torch.matmul(w.T, w) - 1))
        loss = torch.sum(left_side_loss - right_side_loss)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # Normalizing current_P
        w.data = w.data / torch.norm(w.data, dim=0)
    print('current_P', w)
```

I have two problems:

1. If I'm not using normalization (last row of the for loop) the w values just explode.
2. If I do use it, it only works with $k=1$. After that, the returned vectors are the same as the first one.

Ideas what have I done wrong? I think it's connect to not using the Lagrangian correctly but I don't understand why.